# If $A \subseteq B$ and $B$ is countable, then $A$ is either countable, finite, or empty.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

If $A \subseteq B$ and $B$ is countable, then $A$ is either countable, finite, or empty.

I tried proving this statement as follows:

We assume $B$ is a countable set. Thus, there exists $f :\Bbb N → B,$ which is $1$–$1$ and onto. Let $A \subseteq B$ be an infinite subset of $B$.  We must show that $A$ is countable. Let $n_1 = \min\{n \in \Bbb N : f(n) \in A\}.$ As a start to a definition of $g : \Bbb N \to A,$ we set $g(1) = f(n_1).$

Now, let $n_2 = \min\{n \in \Bbb N -\{n_1\}: f(n) \in A\}.$ In, $g : \Bbb N \to A,$ we set $g(2) = f(n_2).$

Similarly,  let $n_3 = \min\{n \in \Bbb N -\{n_1,n_2\}: f(n) \in A\}.$ In, $g : \Bbb N \to A,$ we set $g(3) = f(n_3),$ and so on.

In general, we let $$n_k = \min\{n \in \Bbb N -\{n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_{k-1}\}: f(n) \in A\}.$$ In, $g : \Bbb N \to A,$ we set $g(k) = f(n_k).$

We try to prove that $g$ is a bijective mapping.

For this we have to prove that $g$ is a $1$-$1$ mapping. In other words, we need to show  that, $x,y\in\Bbb N,$ and if  $x\neq y,$ then $g(x)\neq g(y).$ This is indeed true, for if, $g(x)=g(y)\implies f(n_x)=f(n_y).$ This means that $n_x=n_y,$ as $f$ is an injective mapping. Now, if $n_x=n_y,$ this implies that the $x$th smallest natural number and the $y$th smallest natural number in the list $\Bbb  N=\{p\in \Bbb N: f(p)\in B\},$ such that, both  $f(n_x)$ and $f(n_y)$ occurs in $A.$ The only possible conclusion, for this is that $x=y,$ a contradiction. So, $g$ is an injective mapping.

Now, we need to prove that $g$ is onto as well. This follows from the fact that if $a\in A$ then it means, $a\in B$ as well, as $A \subseteq B.$ Again, as $f$ is an onto function so we can say, that $\exists n_r\in \Bbb N,$ i.e we are simply assuming that $n_r$ is the $rth$ smallest  natural number such that $f(n_r)=a.$  But from the definition, of $g$ we have, $g(r)=f(n_r)=a.$ So, $g$ is onto as well. Thus, $A$ is countable.

---

I feel that my way of proving the theorem is justified but the way, I concluded $n_x=n_y\implies x=y,$ (while proving $g$ to be an injective mappping) might be asserted in a much easier way. I want to know that whether  my procedure for proving $x=y,$ stands legit or not.

---

Same is the problem with the portion where, I proved that $g$ is onto. Can the way, by which  I have shown the existence of an $r\in\Bbb N$ such that $g(r)= a$, when $a\in A$,  be improved or not? I want to know whether this portion of the the version of my proof, is rigorous /justified enough?

If something looks erroneous in my proof, please do let me know.

Comment: Isn't the empty set finite?

Comment: @KritikerderElche To be honest, the definition varies from text to text. But alterations or better say, variations like these don't seem to effect the proof in any way.

Comment: I think there's a bit of a gap in your proof.  How do you *know* that the $x$th smallest number in a list and the $y$th smallest number in the list are the same number?  They are, but this is essentially relying on a proof that definition by recursion works.

Comment: To get help with a question like this, you need to provide the definitions and assumed results, because these ideas can be introduced in any number of equivalent ways.

Comment: @ThomasFinley It definitely does not affect the proof. You have also an ambiguity with "countable". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way of proving is that if you assume $A$ were uncountable then $B = A \cup (B\backslash A)$ becomes uncountable, a contradiction. Hence the proof.

Edit: About the way you proved, it seemed okay but a little bit lengthy. You can shorten it by considering the set

$M = \{x \vert f(x)\in A\}$.

This is a subset of

$\mathbb{N}=\{x \vert f(x)\in B\}$.

Now if you take the case where $A$ is not empty or finite then $M$ becomes a countable subset of $\mathbb{N}$. So there will be a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $M$, say $h$. Compose this map with $f$ restricted on $M$ and you will get your required bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$.

Comment: But the theorem "Countable union of countable sets" is mentioned later in the section. So, probably, it's expected to prove it without using this result.

Comment: @ThomasFinley Not necessarily.  This answer only uses that a countable union of *two* countable sets is countable.  You can prove that easily and directly.

Comment: @ThomasFinley We're not using that, we are using the logic that if we have an uncountable set in our union then the union becomes uncountable as well.

Comment: @SoumikMukherjee Ok, but then how do you prove that logic/claim? Also, it wiuld be helpful, if you commented on my way of proving.

Comment: @ThomasFinley I have edited my post. Also $A  \cup B$ has at least as many elements as $A$, right? So if $A$ is uncountable then so is $A \cup B$

Answer (score 2):

Why not try by reductio ad absurdum? Suppose $\;|A|>\aleph_0\;$ . Since $\;A\subset B\;$ there exists an injection

$\;i:A\hookrightarrow B\,,\,\,i(a):=a\;\;\forall\,a\in A\;$ . But this means $\;\aleph_o<|A|\le |B|=\aleph_0\;$ , contradiction. (fill in details).

I think the above is a much simpler proof.